# Why is it not telling me my choice?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
set /p Choice = Choose a number: 
echo %Choice%
pause>nul
```

I want to store my answer in a variable and print it out... Doesn't get any answer.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the spaces around the `=` in your `set` command:

```
@echo off
set /p Choice=Choose a number: 
echo %Choice%
pause>nul
```

You may also notice that `set` doesn't put a space after your prompt, so with your code, it looks like this:

> Choose a number:42
>   42

To fix this, enclose the prompt in double-quotes and put a space at the end:

```
set /p Choice="Choose a number: "
```

Output:

> Choose a number: 42
>   42